# Usage of a comma for emphasis

Tags: punctuation, commas, emphasis

It is grammatically acceptable to say the following?

> Don't forget, they could be tricking us.

Answer (score 6):

If you regard the *don't forget* as an interjection (therefore not an integral part of the sentence), it is grammatical:

> Don't forget, they could be tricking us.

Note that in order for it to be acceptable, the part after the comma must be a complete sentence by itself (*they could be tricking us*).  In a sentence like *Don't forget your book*, in which *your book* is not a sentence by itself, there should never be a comma (**Don't forget, your book*).

Comment: I don't think that's a valid use of a colon. Feasibly you could have an exclamation mark instead of a comma to give more emphasis to "Don't forget", but [this](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp) seems to me a reasonable summary of correct use of the colon, and I don't see OP's sentence fitting any case there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Try Rule 4 in that list.  Though I still disagree with your understanding of colon usage, I took back the part about the colon, since I don't in fact consider it better than the comma.

Comment: #4 is the nearest applicable, I agree - but I think in this sentence the comma does the job perfectly well. My rule 7 (which isn't there!) is *don't use a colon if a comma will suffice*. I see the #4 colon as a "weaker" version of a full stop - if you can't actually replace it with a full stop it's probably inappropriate. Anyway it's gone in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer a colon here, e.g.:

> Don't forget: They could be tricking us.

Perhaps an em-dash:

> Don't forget — they could be tricking us.

A comma *could* be used here, as in the original example, but if feels loose.

Comment: Conventionally, an *em* dash has no leading or trailing space. It is the *en* dash which should have space around it. You could instead just write “dash”, as either dash will do.